# Seed Constraint Program Error For Dynamic Account Creation

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, error

I have an instruction where on the client-side, I'm passing down a game_id to the instruction to be used as part of the seed because this instruction will be called a lot when new game instances are required. However, I'm running to a 2006 error pertaining to a seed constraint being violated. I've verified that it's not the account seeds. I've entered those in correctly. So it has to be an issue with the game_id.

I've tried swapping out .as_bytes() for .as_ref() for the seed values and that doesn't work either. However, owner.key().as_ref() without including game_id in the seed at all works. But then I can't create more than 1 game instance which is not the functionality I need

**rust instruction**

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(game_id: String)]
pub struct CreateGame<'info> {
    #[account(
    init,
    payer = owner,
    space = 8 + GameData::MAX_SIZE,
    seeds = [GameData::SEED.as_bytes(), game_id.as_bytes()],
    bump
    )]
    pub game: Account<'info, GameData>,
    #[account(
    init,
    seeds = [WordVault::SEED.as_bytes(), game_id.as_bytes()],
    bump,
    payer = owner,
    space = 8 + WordVault::MAX_SIZE
    )]
    pub word_vault: Account<'info, WordVault>,
    #[account(
    init,
    payer = owner,
    seeds = [GameTreasury::SEED.as_bytes(), game_id.as_bytes()],
    space = 8 + GameTreasury::MAX_SIZE,
    bump,
    )]
    pub game_treasury: Account<'info, GameTreasury>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub global_game_data: Account<'info, GlobalGameData>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

**client-side hook where instruction is called**

```
const initializeGame = async (wallet: WalletContextState, connection: Connection, gameID: string): Promise<void> => {
        if (!wallet) return;

        let [gameAcctPDA] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [Buffer.from( "GSEED" ), Buffer.from( gameID )],
            PROGRAM_ID
        );
        console.log('gameAcct: ', gameAcctPDA.toString());

        let [wordVaultAcctPDA] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [Buffer.from("WVSEED"), Buffer.from( gameID )],
            PROGRAM_ID
        );
        console.log('wordVaultAcct: ', wordVaultAcctPDA.toString())

        let [gameTreasuryPDA, bump] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [Buffer.from("GTSEED"), Buffer.from( gameID )],
            PROGRAM_ID
        );
        console.log('moneyVaultAcct: ', gameTreasuryPDA.toString())
        console.log('game id: ', gameID)

        const gameAccounts: CreateGameInstructionAccounts = {
            game: gameAcctPDA,
            wordVault: wordVaultAcctPDA,
            gameTreasury: gameTreasuryPDA,
            globalGameData: DEVNET_GLOBAL_GAME_DATA_ACCOUNT,
            owner: wallet.publicKey!
        }

        const gameCreationArgs: CreateGameInstructionArgs = {
            name: 'Test',
            minDeposit: 0.1,
            gameId: gameID
        }

        const transactionInstruction = createCreateGameInstruction(gameAccounts, gameCreationArgs);

        try {
            const tx = new Transaction().add(transactionInstruction);
            tx!.feePayer = wallet!.publicKey!;

            const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
            tx.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;

            const sent = await wallet.wallet?.adapter?.sendTransaction(tx, connection)
            console.log('tx data: ', sent);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error creating game', error);
        }
    };
```

**view where hook is being triggered**

```
const handleCreateGame = async () => {
        // TODO: pull current game id from global game data state
        const gameID = `game_${1}`
        await initializeGame(wallet!, devNetConnection, gameID)
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the endianess? Afaik Solana rust defaults to little-endian, whereas typescript is kind of inconsistent with this. Try inversing your Buffer.from call on the client side. Alternatively you could also just have GameID as a u128 or even u256 which would allow you to create tons of games and make serialization simpler.